# Why I am getting out of range error of the double range being broken?

Tags: mysql, sql

Although the limit of double is huge.

```
create table numerictype2 (
    c1 decimal(3,2),
    c2 float(3,2),
    c3 double(5,2)
);

insert into numerictype2 values #insert values
(2.323,2.323,2.323),
(1.5,1.4,111.65);
```

Why I am getting this error:

> Error Code: 1264. Out of range value for column 'c3' at row 2

Comment: Please tag the database you are using.

Comment: I get a warning for c1, not c3. Are you sure you produce the error with this exact same input?

Comment: Error 1264 is a MySQL error ,so I added the tag.  However, this does not reproduce on MySQL 8 -- https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=741fbc77eca123da4790471a6c049b66.

Comment: I can only conclude that the values posted in the question was not the ones that generated the error, perhaps you had 1111.65 for col3 in the second row.

Comment: I tried it once again and now it worked.No change in SQL statements.Worked fine with a warning in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying a small size and precision for your `double` column. The first parameter with a value of 5 denotes there can be a maximum of 5 digits in the number stored. The second parameter indicates how many of these can be to the right of decimal point. You need to increase the size and decimal places.

Comment: This is all true and well but how does it answer the question?

Comment: The OP assumed "the limit of double is huge" but did not consider this factor which can quite limit the double type

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in exceeding the double limit, but you specified that the values can only have 2 digits after the decimal point. You are trying to insert values with three digits after the decimal point. That's why you get out of range error.
I suggest rounding or truncating the values before inserting.

Comment: Did you verify this? When I do the insert then MySql quietly rounds the values to a precision of 2 without any error or warning. How did you do to get an error?

Comment: When I tried the insert, it didn't throw an error. However, the error might have been caused by the settings of the database, schema.